# Cannot import nltk

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I want to import nltk in a program to download the corpus.
But I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Android.DESKTOP-S6P9R3V.001/Desktop/ud120-projects-master/blah.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Users\Android.DESKTOP-S6P9R3V.001\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "C:\Users\Android.DESKTOP-S6P9R3V.001\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "C:\Users\Android.DESKTOP-S6P9R3V.001\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\chunk\api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.util import ChunkScore
  File "C:\Users\Android.DESKTOP-S6P9R3V.001\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\chunk\util.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.tag.mapping import map_tag
  File "C:\Users\Android.DESKTOP-S6P9R3V.001\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from nltk.tag.sequential    import (SequentialBackoffTagger, ContextTagger,
  File "C:\Users\Android.DESKTOP-S6P9R3V.001\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 25, in <module>
    from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
  File "C:\Users\Android.DESKTOP-S6P9R3V.001\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\classify\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
ImportError: No module named scikitlearn
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I had downloaded nltk using anaconda and I use a windows machine.

Comment: Use nltk.download() for downloading collection.

Comment: I'm doing that but it shows that nltk cannot be imported

Comment: So `import nltk` is not working?

Comment: Please see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the module is called sklearn, alternately scikit-learn.  See https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using

```
import scikit-learn
```

there is no module called scikit-learn.
you should be using

```
import sklearn
```

If the above doesn't work,

Try using anaconda python
you should try the following

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

and add this for performance - if it doesn't install

```
conda install numpy
```